# Filter Duplicated records in one column by another column SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, filter, netezza

I have a table that contains duplicated values in one row: `[A_Number]` but the others are not, so I need to filter these duplicated records using another field:`[Area_code]`, but `[A_Number]` is not always have duplicated values,

Using the below example:

| Area_Code | A_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 955 | 2324356 |
| 55 | 2324356 |
| 945 | 2324356 |
| 45 | 2324356 |
| 940 | 8675643 |
| 13 | 4450987 |

- The issue is: the `A_Number` may have duplicated records due to `Area_Code`, every duplicated `A_Number` has 2 `Area_Code` one starts with `9` and have 3 digits but the other without `9` and have 2 digits, so I need to get Area_Code without `9` and have 2 digits only.
- If `A_Number` have one `Area_Code` that starts with 9 and have 3 digits, we will remove `9` from `Area_Code`
- if A_Number `A_Number` have one `Area_Code` that  without 9 and have 2 digits will be the same
- [edited] the `A_Number` could have a different `Area_Code` like the `A_Number`:2324356

The expected results

| Area_Code | A_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 55 | 2324356 |
| 45 | 2324356 |
| 40 | 8675643 |
| 13 | 4450987 |

Answer (score 1):

If `area_code` will always duplicates last two digits ie `9xx` and `xx` (where `xx` are same in all occurences) then a simple group by with appropriate substring would work out -

```sql
select a_number, case 
                   when area_code like '9%' 
                     then substring(area_code, 2)
                   else area_code
                 end as code
from t
group by a_number, code
```

However if `xx` are different numbers then you'd have to choose how to restrict them to the ones you want

```
-- take only the first (min) or last (max)
select a_number, min(code) as first_code, max(code) as last_code
from 
    select a_number, case 
                   when area_code like '9%' 
                     then substring(area_code, 2)
                   else area_code
                 end as code
    from t
    group by a_number, code ) tmp
group by a_number
```

Comment: Yes `area_code` `xx` are different numbers, and there is a chance for unique `a_number` that have a different `area_code` like the example in the thread

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

I *think* you basically want `min()` with some string parsing logic:

```
select a_number,
       (case when min(area_code) like '9%'
             then substring(min(area_code), 2)
             else min(area_code)
        end)
from t
group by a_number;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have an edit,  as the A_Number could have a different Area_Code like the A_Number:2324356 in example